# Rails - how to add an Index to a database that sorts by 2 where clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following:

```
      @count = current_user.participations.joins(:topic).where("topic.status = ? AND participations.status = ?","open","unread").count
```

Right now I have an index for:

- topic.status
- participations.status

1 for each table, Do I need to add an index that combines both to optimize this query?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add an index on each column. I don't believe you can combine columns from separate tables within a single index.